# Class that runs a JS function does not work with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to insert html code with innerHTML, which inserts a input that has the class .flatpickr-date.

```
var html = '<input type="text" class="flatpickr-date">'

document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = html;
```

In a javascript file I have the following, which applies to the .flatpickr-date class and uses a "flatpickr" plugin method:

```
$ (".flatpickr-date").flatpickr(

    {
        dateFormat: "d / m / Y",
        maxDate: new Date (), // 30 days from now
        "locale": "in"
    }

);
```

The previous code what it does is to generate a calendar in the input that has the flatpickr-date class. The problem is that he does not appear, as if he was not reading the class

Comment: Are you creating the new html **after** the `flatpickr()` is called?

Comment: @Taplar Yes you are correct

Comment: Then it's not going to exist at the time you perform your initialization.  You need to initialize again after you insert the new one

Comment: let me see if i understood. You want to create with js an input an then initialize in that input flatpickr plugin?

Comment: @Taplar your answer is correct. Please, publish it so I take it as the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dynamically creating elements in the future, I would suggest making a reusable method.

```
function initializeFlatPicker (context) {
  $(".flatpickr-date", context || document).flatpickr({
    dateFormat: "d / m / Y",
    maxDate: new Date (), // 30 days from now
    "locale": "in"
  });
}

initializeFlatPicker();
```

This will do the same thing you are doing now for the first initialize.  Then later when you make a new one...

```
var html = '<input type="text" class="flatpickr-date">'
var parent = document.getElementById('id');

parent.innerHTML = html;

initializeFlatPicker(parent);
```

This will perform the initialization again, but **only** for the new element.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', function () { ... document.getElementById("flatpickr").flatpickr({}) }) `

Answer (score 0):

Well, What you need is first create the input with js and then start the plugin. Here is the code

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.1/flatpickr.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="form">
        </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.1/flatpickr.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var html = '<input type="text" class="flatpickr-date">'
            document.getElementById('form').innerHTML = html;   
            $ (".flatpickr-date").flatpickr(
                {
                    dateFormat: "d / m / Y",
                    maxDate: new Date (), // 30 days from now
                    "locale": "in"
                }
            );          
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The live working example

https://codepen.io/rollrodrig/pen/KjJGyy

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on dynamic creation of the div which will contain the calendar you can instantiate the calendar plugin at the time you create the div.

For example:

```
var calendar={
    createCal:function(id){
        var html = '<input type="text" class="flatpickr-date">'
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;    
        this.init(id);
    },

    init:function(id){  
        $ ("#' + id  + '.flatpickr-date").flatpickr(
            {
                dateFormat: "d / m / Y",
                maxDate: new Date (), // 30 days from now
                "locale": "in"
            }
        );
    }
}
```